# use each() to push element to JSON

Tags: jquery, json, each

I want to push some value to JSON by each()

**this is my HTML code:**

```
<div class="user-dat" data-unread="61222"></div>
<div class="user-dat" data-unread="61555"></div>
<div class="user-dat" data-unread="61206"></div>
```

**my jquery code**

```
$(".user-data").each(function(index,value(){
  var unreadID = [];
  unreadID.push($(this).attr('data-unread'));
}
```

here is my output:

```
["61222"]
["61555"]
["61206"]
```

but I want this:

```
["61222","61555","61206"]
```

how can I fix my code , or have any idea suggestion?

thanks.

Comment: Make a choice between "user-dat" and "user-data".

Comment: @Lix oops, I really don't accept any answers, oh my god, thanks for your comments, I'll accept right now! sorry about the mistake

Comment: those answers are work for me, can I accept every answers or only one :| ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are redefining your array with each iteration. Define the array outside of the `each` function like this:

```
var unreadID = [];
$( ".user-data" ).each( function( index,value ) {
  unreadID.push( $(this).attr( "data-unread" ) );
});
```

If you place the array's definition within the loop, for each item, the array will be reset to `[]` - an empty array. Defining the variable outside ensures that you keep the existing values as you continue to iterate over the rest of the elements.

Comment: @muki - naa - this isn't that bad at all. I've seen worse ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var array = $('.user-dat').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('unread')
}).get()
```

In your case you needed to declare the array in a shared context so that every call to the each callback doesn't reset the array

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, and I learn .map() from the answer, thanks!

Comment: @Grundy not a problem because jQuery will handle it

Comment: @ArunPJohny oh, you right! it seemed to me that used the native method

Answer (score 3):

You're redefining the **`unreadID`** on each iteration.  So declare it outside the `$.each` will solve your problem.